# Store Binary files on GAE/J + Google DataStore

Tags: google-app-engine, binaryfiles, google-cloud-datastore

I'm building application on Google AppEngine with Java (GAE/J) and all my data will be stored in Google DataStore. Now, what if I want to save some binary file, let's say Images (JPG, PNG, etc), DOC, TXT, Video Files how do i deal with these? Or what if i want to stream video files (SWF) where and how should i store those files and when I redeploy my app i don't loose any data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depends on whether you're talking about static files or dynamic... If they're static created by you, you can upload them subject to a 10MB/3000 file max but Google doesn't offer a CDN or anything.

If they're dynamic, uploaded by your users or created by your application, the datastore supports BlobProperties: you can dump any kind of binary data you want in there as long as it's less than 1MB per entity. If they're larger you can consider another service like S3 or Mosso's cloud files. This can be a better solution for serving files directly to users because these guys can offer CDN service but it's not cheap. On the other hand your latency back to GAE will be much higher than storing the data in Google's Datastore and you'll have to pay for transit on both sides so it's something to take into account if you're going to be processing the files on App Engine.

Comment: Now you have a blob service in GAE for files up to 50MB. It's separate from Datastore but it's for dynamic files. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 1):

[Google App Engine Virtual File System (GaeVFS)](http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/)